# Double loop to single loop

Tags: c++, loops

**Updated** 
This is a basic programming doubt, i just started to learn c and c++
i have two loops i.e.

```
if (n==null)
{

do loop 1

}
else //(n!=null)
{

do loop2

}
```

now I have to update the above code, with a single loop i.e. when `n==null` or `n!=null` do the loop 1 alone

how can i update.?

can i do like this

```
while(n==null || n!=null)
{

do loop 1

}
```

is `||` operator above does the job what i expected?

Comment: `n==null && n=!null` will always evaluate to `false`.

Comment: `n` cant be null and not null at the same time.. unless the programmer is Schrodinger :)

Comment: your predicate can be read if n is null and n is not null. which is naturaly always false. what exactly are you trying to acomplish here ?

Comment: You say _when n==null and n!=null do the loop 1 alone_, but you mean _when n==null **or** n!=null do the loop 1 alone_. And since `n` is either `NULL` or not, the ored value is always true and you basically have an infinite loop. Try to show us how your loops actually look like.

Comment: sorry i wrongly understood and asked the question, it is when n==null or n!=null do the loop 1

Comment: @user1983117 read what Shahbaz writes - `anything == null || anything != null` is **always true**

Comment: sorry everyone i understood wrongly and asked the question initially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

```
while(n==null || n!=null)
{
    do loop1
}
```

is an infinite loop because `n==null || n!=null` is **always true**.

Probably you mean

```
if(n==null || n!=null)
{
    do loop1
}
```

which for the above remark is simply

```
do loop1
```

In any case I suggest you to give a look to the [Truth Tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table).

Comment: so if(n==null || n!=null)
{
    loop1
} will execute the loop 1 if any one of the condition is true right?

Comment: This code works but is not necessary since the condition (n==null || n!=null) is always true. So is the same as writing only "loop1"